# No option to run a .cpp file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and C++. I want to run a simple C++ program to print hello world. but I don't have an option to run the file. I first used Visual Studio for Python and so there was on python workload.

Now I have installed the C++ workload that say - Desktop development or something like that. But all the options to run the file are in python.

[image: This is the image]

Comment: .cpp files aren't run. A project containing .cpp files is built into an .exe, and _that_ is run. I'm guessing you haven't created a project?

Comment: umm i think so. Wait a second

Comment: You have to create a solution and a project first. AFAIK you can't compile, link and run a file on it's own. (allthough it's possible when you invoke compiler & linker from command line).

Comment: @Emperor See [C++ Tutorial: Hello World](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-tutorial-hello-world/) for a step-by-step introduction.

Comment: it worked. Thank you! and sorry for such idiotic mistakes. its an IDE so, difficult for beginners to understand

Comment: You need a C++ compiler, like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). You need an editor, like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). You need a debugger, like [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). If you install [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop, you can get all of them.

Comment: I shall close this thread now

Comment: also I installed Mingw. Is it important? Also should I uninstall it now?

Comment: i don't know what I compile it with. Please help

Comment: Should I delete MinGW? Because VS doesn't seem to use it

Comment: Avoid mingw on windows, visual studio is the much simpler option for beginners, no need to uninstall it, it doesn't seem to be doing any harm

Comment: be avare that Visual Studio COde if you use that (hard to tell )  doesn't have compiler, it's an editor with ability to hook up some compiler toolchains. It sounds you have t read some introduction to even how that everything works or you'll stay mystified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Win32 Console Application project, add there your cpp file, then compile and run.

Comment: In fact, VS will create a cpp file automatically. He only needs to use the project wizzard.